# Eloquent doesn't update all records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

What I want to do is update all of the records in field **book_id** of **TableB** to be equal to **TableA**  **book_id**. But it only updates a few records, *19 out of 7862* to be precise.

I did this many times hoping that consequent 19 record updates will eventually reach 7862 but to my bewilderment it's still 19.

```
TableA:
book_id
ibooks_id -> equal to TableB.book_id

TableB:
book_id -> change to TableA.book_id
```

Codes I tried:

```
$books = TableAModel::join("TableB", "TableA.ibooks_id", '=', "TableB.book_id")
                    ->update(array("TableB.book_id" => "TableA.book_id"));
```

and also:

```
$tableBItems = TableBModel::all();
    TableBModel::unguard();
    foreach($tableBItems as $tableBitem) {
        $TableAItem = TableAModel::where('ibooks_id',$tableBitem->book_id)->first();
        if(isset($TableAItem->book_id)) {
            $tableBitem->book_id = $TableAItem->book_id;
            $tableBitem->save();
        }
    }
```

Do you have a better approach to this? Or maybe this can be **done via pure mysql query**, thanks.

Models:

```
class TableBModel extends Eloquent {

    public $table = 'TableB';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
class TableAModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'TableA';
    public $primaryKey = 'book_id';
}
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Are there only 19 records of the join TableA.ibooks_id = TableB.book_id ? What is the result of the join? Could you post the 19 rows that were updated and some rows that were not updated?

Answer (score 1):

I say a good practice working with any kind of RDBMS/SQL is to let the SQL engine do as much of the `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` as possible as it is highly optimized for this type of work. If you are planning to perform the same operation multiple times within your application, just write it into a procedure in MySQL as such example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_changeTableB_book_id();
DELIMITER //
BEGIN

-- you can leave out the code above if running ad-hoc query, but replace // below with ;

UPDATE TableB INNER JOIN TableA
ON TableB.book_id = TableA.ibooks_id
SET TableB.book_id = TableA.book_id//

-- you can leave out the code below if running ad-hoc query

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then when you want to use it (if not ad-hoc) just code in Eloquent to MySQL `CALL sp_changeTableB_book_id`

You may be interested in [this post on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/search-script-code-efficiency/51962#51962) to see some of the advantages of doing this using a stored procedure in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst you need to check the rows that your query is returning. So rather than updating it directly, first do a select * to count the number of rows being returned, because these rows will be updated.

The sample is
oin("TableB", "TableA.ibooks_id", '=', "TableB.book_id")

Select * 
from tableA
join tableB on tableA.ibooks_id = TableB.book_id

Using this query you will be able to get the number of rows where your join clause is working.

Also the second approach that you tried, is extremely expensive, you are getting all the rows, then again you are running a for loop over all the rows, in which in every iteration you are performing another DB query.